# Custom rendering datasource syntax without breaking experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, presentation, datasource

I'd like to be able to use a custom datasource syntax for renderings and sublayouts.

In particular I'd like to be able to handle custom prefixes for various different usages. The main one being site-relative paths such as:

```
site:*[@@templateid="{...guid...}"]
```

I've had no problem using the custom syntax from codebehind, as it's available as a raw string.

The issue arises in Experience Editor mode. If I use a custom datasource syntax [the frame of the rendering breaks](https://youtu.be/X9LImaSU-zI).

Is there a pipeline I need to use to tell Sitecore what item or ID it should be using for the rendering?

Comment: From what I remember, you need to override `Sitecore.Pipelines.GetRenderingDatasource.GetDatasourceLocation` (check config for `GetRenderingDatasource` pipeline). But it was ages ago when I modified things there so you need to dig more on your own

Comment: @MarekMusielak, I'll give that a try again. I'm pretty certain the `getRenderingDatasource` pipeline is only used when the datasource selection dialog is opened. I had attempted to modify the `resolveRenderingDatasource` pipeline, but I couldn't figure out what changes might be necessary and I haven't seen much of anything online for handling this behavior.

Comment: also, in case it makes a difference, I'm in Sitecore 8.2

Comment: iirc, SXA introduce a $site variable that could be used in datasources.

Comment: @PeteNavarra, thanks for the tip, it led me to [a post that looks promising](http://sitecorecode.com/index.php/tag/sxa/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Sitecore to resolve datasources using custom logic, you can add a pipeline processor to the `resolveRenderingDatasource` pipeline in `Sitecore.config`:

```
<resolveRenderingDatasource>
  <processor type="Example.DataSourceService, Example"/>
</resolveRenderingDatasource>
```

The `DataSourceService` processor can then inject any custom logic it needs for resolving the datasource string to an ID:

```
public class DataSourceService
{
  public void Process(ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
  {
    if (!args.Datasource.StartsWith("site:"))
      return;
    if (Context.Database == null || Context.Site == null)
    {
      args.Datasource = "";
      return;
    }

    var item = CustomQuery(args.Datasource);
    args.Datasource = item.ID.ToString();
  }
}
```

### MVC:

If you're in an MVC environment you'll need to also add a processor to the `mvc.customizeRendering` pipeline in `Sitecore.MvcExperienceEditor.config`:

```
<mvc.customizeRendering>
  <processor type="Example.ResolveRenderingDatasource, Example" patch:after="*"/>
</mvc.customizeRendering>
```

The `ResolveRenderingDatasource` processor needs to call the `resolveRenderingDatasource` pipeline.

Also make sure you add reference to `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics`.

```
using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.ResolveRenderingDatasource;

public class ResolveRenderingDatasource : CustomizeRenderingProcessor
{
  public override void Process(CustomizeRenderingArgs args)
  {
    var rendering = args.Rendering;
    var renderingDatasourceArgs = new ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs(rendering.DataSource);
    CorePipeline.Run("resolveRenderingDatasource", renderingDatasourceArgs);
    rendering.DataSource = renderingDatasourceArgs.Datasource;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom processor in `resolveRenderingDatasource` pipeline:

```
<!--
  Allows developers to override the default logic for resolving the data source for renderings. 
-->
<resolveRenderingDatasource>
    ...
    <processor type="MyCustom.Project.Processors.ResolveRenderingDataSource, MyCustom.Project" />
</resolveRenderingDatasource>
```

Your processor needs to set the `args.Datasource` property to either an item path or a guid:

```
using Sitecore.Pipelines.ResolveRenderingDatasource;

namespace MyCustom.Project.Processors
{
    public class ResolveRenderingDataSource
    {
        public void Process(ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
        {
            var source = args.Datasource;
            if (source.StartsWith("site:"))
            {
                /* Add your own custom logic to resolve and set the datasource */
                args.Datasource = ResolveCustomDatasource(source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to update this with my solution in a few days when I have some time. You're absolutely right about the `resolveRenderingDatasource` pipeline as a start. I'm in an MVC project so I also had to add an MVC-specific pipeline handler to avoid some errors in experience editor mode. Later I ran into some issues with some null references during publishing as well. I'm not sure how much of what I've currently got would Just Work™ in Web Forms.